# SMS war continues, ideas welcome

Tags: sms

I am trying to make U9 telit modem send SMS messages. I think I handle protocol correctly, at least, I manage to send them, but only under these circumstances: the native application was executed beforehand, and killed by task manager (without giving it a chance to initialize things).

It looks like the supplied application is good at doing certain initialization/deinitialization which is critical. I also see the difference between the two states in output of AT+CIND command. When I am trying to do things on my own, it returns zeroes (including signal quality), but when I run the same command after killing the native application, the output looks reasonable.

I am out nearly of ideas. I have tried many things, including attempts to spy at modem's COM ports (didn't work). Haven't tried setting windows hooks to see what the application is trying to get thru.

Perhaps you have encountered a similar situation?

Comment: Does it work if you connect via terminal and just bash out commands? If you just see numbers instead of OK try issuing ATQ0 V1

Comment: I interact with it okay but it wouldn't send sms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agg's "Advanced Serial Port Monitor" actually helped a lot. Sometimes it caused blue screen, but it helped uncover secret commands which seem to help. AT+PCFULL is not described anywhere on the net, for example. The real trigger of non-operatio was AT+CFUN, the power disable/standby feature.

Also, it appeared that we have more issues. At first, the modem appears on the bus only as disk drive. It doesn't want to appear as any other devices before the drivers are installed. So, the U9 Telit software sends an IOCTL to disk driver to tell the modem to reappear as more devices (modem, 3 serial ports, another disk drive).